# How to programatically get the status value of a Content Type column using C#?

Tags: development, content-type, column

I am attempting to read the property of the Item content type which shows the Required, Hidden or Optional property for a particular column.

```
 if (spList.TryFindContentType("Item", out SPContentType itemContentType))
 {
     foreach (var field in itemContentType.Fields)
     {
         // How do I access the status value for a particular column? E.g. Hidden, Required or Optional?
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the columns in a Content Type eg "Item" Content Type, you could use the code snippet below to get it directly:

```
 using (SPSite site =new SPSite("http://demoaam.contoso2016.com/sites/dev/"))
        {
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"];
            foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Title " + item["Title"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Column Name 1 "+ item["Col_x0020_Name_x0020_1"]);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Field is hosted in Item Object, use item[internal field name] will get the field value.

[image]

[image]